# How to make Custom File Chooser UI HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

My company is making a webpage that is a sort of kiosk mode in google chrome. We will have windows tablets locked into it. However we have an outside system in an iframe that requires uploading files. Would it be possible to make a custom file uploading UI, so that the user can only choose files from a certain folder, so they cannot access the whole file system.

- I have already tried to set the value attribute like so `value="C:\path\to\file.txt"`, but you cannot do this for security reasons.
- I was also had an idea that maybe the files could be on my server instead of the tablet. I don't know how this could work.
- **EDIT:** I am currently using a chrome extension for other stuff. Could I somehow use the chrome extension to set the value of the input?

I am proficient at HTML and CSS so I could make the UI, but I couldn't make it function.

Comment: I don't think that's something you can do from a browser using standard HTML/JS/CSS, you might have to make an actual application for this, or make a server side file browser.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - who adds file to the "secure" folder? You could just add some sort of fixed UI that shows all images you wanna be selectable - server side file browser is a good hint!

Comment: @zack6849 Could I do it with a chrome extension?

Comment: @lumio I need to select the file for a standard file input

Comment: @Pete, why has it to be a standard file input? You could use a UI and then fill a hidden form element with javascript, containing the filename.

Comment: @lumio it is a third party system, that is inside an iframe.

Comment: Okay now I understand. So no, I don't think it is possible

Comment: @lumio Okay thank you.